# CSS3 keyframe animation on 100% width/height backgrounds

Tags: css, css-animations

I am trying to animate background of an element that is 100% wide and tall. It is a simple CSS3 animation using steps to go through the sprite image.

The animation looks like this:

```
.play-intro{animation: play 2s steps(6);}
@keyframes play {
from { background-position:    0 0 ; }
to { background-position:      -7800px 0 }
}
```

The issue is that I am seeing each sprite change, it is not working as it should be. I don't know, but I believe it is maybe due to background-size:cover property. Any advice on this?

I created a fiddle to recreate the issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/QKwjM/1/

And this is the fiddle in fullscreen, the issue is best seen there.
http://jsfiddle.net/QKwjM/1/embedded/result/

Comment: the issue is that you see each sprite change? I think changing the sprite is what you're trying to achieve!? If I understand you right, the issue is that the animation seems to "lag" in any way. Have you tried setting the percent/step values instead of from/to?

Comment: It should be smoothly animated. That is why I am using keyframe animation. See this for example http://jsfiddle.net/simurai/CGmCe/

Comment: @Adrift Now it acts like a slider, that is not the desired behaviour I want. You can check the fiddle two comments above or this link http://davidwalsh.name/firefox-animation , just click on view demo, it is also steps based.

Answer (score 1):

If you set

```
background-size: cover;
```

the background-size is variable (adjusts to the space) and that breaks the animation.

Since your last keyframe is -7800px, the background-size-x must be exactly that

```
background-size: 7800px 701px;
```

Comment: Yes, you are right about that. But now I get 701px tall background. So, basically it is impossible to do what I want with 100% height and background-size:cover ?